# Book recommendations on geometrical methods for physicists (like Topology, Diff. Geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, topology

I would like to obtain a book that has to do with geometrical methods/subjects for physicists. When I say geometrical methods/subjects I mean things like Topology, Differential Geometry, Lie derivative/groups, Manifolds, vector fields etc.
Note: I do not want a book containing only Topology.